# Have a Microsoft Azure web app chatbot proactively contact a user using e-mail or Twilio from a table/list of preset users

Tags: javascript, azure, botframework, azure-table-storage, chatbot

I have a simple web app chatbot made with Azure. It is very simple, it will ask a user 3 questions, record the answers to a storage table and repeat the answers back to the user.

I have connected it to Twilio and e-mail using the Channels tab in azure portal. I wonder, is it possible to have a table or database with e-mail addresses or phonenumbers that the bot will contact, preferably if perhaps a variable for a certain address switched from false to true that address would be contacted.

This is the closest example I have found however it uses Skype. Not e-mail or Twilio. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-CreateNewConversation

I would like something like this part

```
// Every 5 seconds, check for new registered users and start a new dialog
setInterval(function() {
  var newAddresses = userStore.splice(0);

  newAddresses.forEach(function(address) {
    console.log('Starting survey for address:', address);

    // new conversation address, copy without conversationId
    var newConversationAddress = Object.assign({}, address);

    delete newConversationAddress.conversation;

    // start survey dialog
    bot.beginDialog(newConversationAddress, 'survey', null, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        // error ocurred while starting new conversation. Channel not supported?
        bot.send(new builder.Message()
          .text('This channel does not support this operation: ' + err.message)
          .address(address));
      }
    });
  });
```

to scan a table and if a variable switches it will extract the address from the table and set it as a `address` variable.

I believe I can figure that out myself however I require help to learn how to make the bot contact a user without the user contacting the bot first, instead using a list of preset users.

If there is any documentation regarding the e-mail channel for a web app bot I have not been able to find it, I would like to know how to have the bot send a e-mail to a user and if there are any JavaScript classes I could use to use the e-mail channel in my bots `app.js` code.

I hope I made myself understandable, many thanks for any help

Comment: For your scenario, I think it's appropriate to save the email or phone info into a database in bot application, and then leverage [Function App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) to send email in background

Answer (score 0):

With regard to contacting a user without them having first contacted the bot on the Email and Twilio channels you can do the following.

Set up the addresses for each like so:

**Email**

```
var emailAddress = 
{    
 channelId: 'email',
 user: { id: <userEmail> },
 bot: { id: <botEmail>, name: <botName> },
 serviceUrl: 'https://email.botframework.com/' 
};
```

**SMS**

```
var sms = 
{
 user: { id: '<userphone>' },
 bot: { id: '<botphone>' },
 conversation: {id: '<userphone>'},
 channelId: 'sms',
 serviceUrl: 'https://sms.botframework.com'
};
```

Note that SMS will not work with a trial twilio number, but will work fine with a purchased number.

After you have your addresses set up, you can route each of them through something like the following code.

```
var message = new builder.Message()
    .address(address) 
    .text(<messageText>); 

try {
  console.log(message);
  bot.send(message);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Will edit this to include loading the user list later if needed.